# How to pass value to substitution variable oracle command

Tags: .net, oracle

I have an issue with substitution variable of oracle :

SQL command :

```
SELECT * FROM &tablename
```

I want pass value for &tablename with OracleCommand as : OracleParams.

Please help me

Comment: Arguably the best way to communicate with Oracle from a .Net program is to use ADO.Net, and Oracle-specific .Net namespace "System.Data.OracleClient".   Q: Is that an option for you?  Here's a tutorial that uses ADO.Net with OracleParameter: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/UsingOracleParameter.htm

Answer (score 0):

Substitution variables are purely SQL*Plus instrument. With ODP.NET and other Oracle clients you can build and execute any dynamic SQL command.